# How to change value of child of the same parent that entered other child value in forgot password feature in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a Firebase ecommerce app, I have been trying to update the password when passing the email of the user in "forgot password" feature but i can't get it right.

Here is my Firebase structure:

[image: Firebase structure]

I want the method to get the user with the entered email, then update his password to a new one.

Here is my code:

```
set_new_pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUserDatabase = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user_email);
        String user_newpass=new_password.getText().toString();
        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put("password",user_newpass);
       // hashMap.put("email",user_email);
        checkUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    //String username_ofuser =hashMap.get("username").toString();
                    reference.child(user_username).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                        Toast.makeText(SetNewPassword.this, "your password is successfully changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

How can I achieve my results?

this code should change the password of the user that has his email entered but it doesn't change anything actually so what can i do to make it work correctly??

Comment: Have you tried to add the Failure listener to see if something goes wrong when you call `.updateChildren(hashMap)`?

Comment: I'm with Alex here: at first glance this code looks like it should work. If a failure listener doesn't show a problem, try debugging the problem locally. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?